# OpenCV используя Cam2API

Tags: opencv, камера, android-camera

Как получать кадр из Cam2Api обрабатывать c помощью openCV и отображать на экране.
В риалтайме

Ничего не смог найти по поводу cam2api и openCV вместе, с JavaCameraView все доступно расписано.

```
session.setRepeatingRequest(mCaptureRequestBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
```

Я так понимаю что данный метод берет изображение с камеры и отправляет на экран.
Как мне делать пред обработку изображения?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/lirugo/screenDetector
кому интересно смотрите код тут

```
private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener = new
            ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                    Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                    if(image != null) {
                        // Get buffer
                        ByteBuffer yBuff = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                        ByteBuffer uBuff = image.getPlanes()[1].getBuffer();
                        ByteBuffer vBuff = image.getPlanes()[2].getBuffer();
                        ByteArrayOutputStream  outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        byte[] yByte = new byte[yBuff.remaining()];
                        byte[] uByte = new byte[uBuff.remaining()];
                        byte[] vByte = new byte[vBuff.remaining()];
                        yBuff.get(yByte);
                        uBuff.get(uByte);
                        vBuff.get(vByte);

                        // Create converting byte[] NV21
                        try {
                            outputStream.write(yByte);
                            for (int i=0; i < uByte.length; i++) {
                                outputStream.write(vByte[i]);
                                outputStream.write(uByte[i]);
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        byte[] imageBytes = outputStream.toByteArray();

                        //Some var
                        int x,y,width,height,total;
                        width = image.getWidth();
                        height = image.getHeight();
                        total = width * height;
                        x = width / 2;
                        y = height / 2;

                        // Get YUV coordinates  for x y position
                        int YCord     = y * width + x;
                        int UCord     = (y >> 1) * (width) + x + total + 1;
                        int VCord     = (y >> 1) * (width) + x + total;

                        // Get YUV colors
                        int Y = (0xFF & imageBytes[YCord]) - 16;
                        int U = (0xFF & imageBytes[UCord]) - 128;
                        int V = (0xFF & imageBytes[VCord]) - 128;

                        Y = clamp(Y, 16, 235);
                        U = clamp(U, -112, 112);
                        V = clamp(V, -112, 112);

//                        Y = 81;
//                        U = -38;
//                        V = 112;

//                        if (Y < 0) Y += 255;
//                        if (U < 0) U += 127; else U -= 128;
//                        if (V < 0) V += 127; else V -= 128;

                        int r = (int) (Y + 1.370705 * V);
                        int g = (int) (Y - 0.698001 * V - 0.337633 * U);
                        int b = (int) (Y + 1.732446 * U);

                        //Clamp
                        r = clamp(r, 0, 255);
                        g = clamp(g, 0, 255);
                        b = clamp(b, 0, 255);

                        final YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(outputStream.toByteArray(), ImageFormat.NV21, image.getWidth(),image.getHeight(), null);
                        ByteArrayOutputStream outBitmap = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                        yuvImage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0,image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()), 100, outBitmap);

                        imageBytes = outBitmap.toByteArray();
                        try {
                            FileOutputStream fos = null;
                            fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"MAGNET1" +
                                    ".jpg"));
                            fos.write(imageBytes);
                            fos.close();
                            String text = String.valueOf("( R" + r + ", G" + g + ", B" + b + " )");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        image.close();
//                        try {
//                            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
//                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//                            e.printStackTrace();
//                        }
                    }
                }
            };
```